# Simplify multiple Scenarios with Scenario Outline

Tags: cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

The [Scenario Outline](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#scenario-outline) keyword can be used to run the same Scenario multiple times, with different combinations of values.

How to simplify multiple Scenarios with Scenario Outline when paramters are tables.

```
Scenario: 1 row
    Given I import data to a table
      | col1      | col2     |
      | value1-1  | value1-2 |

    When I execuate the logic1

    Then I can get data
      | result_col1      | result_col2     |
      | result-value1-1  | result-value1-2 |


Scenario: 2 rows
    Given I import data to a table
      | col1      | col2     |
      | value1-1  | value1-2 |
      | value2-1  | value2-2 |

    When I execuate the logic1

    Then I can get data
      | result_col1      | result_col2     |
      | result-value1-1  | result-value1-2 |


Scenario: 3 rows
    Given I import data to a table
      | col1      | col2     |
      | value1-1  | value1-2 |
      | value2-1  | value2-2 |
      | value3-1  | value3-2 |

    When I execuate the logic1

    Then I can get data
      | result_col1      | result_col2     |
      | result-value1-1  | result-value1-2 |
      | result-value3-1  | result-value3-2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same steps and the same expected values ​​in the columns.

You can simplify With **Scenario Outline** as follows:

```
Scenario Outline: Example Scenario Outline 
    Given that the user import the following data to a table
        | Col1   | Col2   | 
        | <Col1> | <Col2> |
    When the user perform the logic action
    Then I can get data "<Result_col1>" and "<Result_col2>" 

    Examples: 
        | Id | Scenario   | Col1     | Col2     | result_col1     | result_col2     | 
        | 1  | value1-1   | value1-1 | value1-2 | result-value1-1 | result-value1-2 |
        | 2  | value2-1   | value2-1 | value2-2 | result-value2-1 | result-value2-2 |
```

**Note:** in your code you can take the values ​​as list or datatables with Jackson you can create different DTO an map the Data within steps and Dto class

```
    @Given("^that the user import the following data to a table$")
    public void that_the_user_import_the_following_data_to_a_table(DataTable yourClassExampleDTO) throws Throwable {

        List<YourClassExampleDTO> lstYourClassExampleDTO = yourClassExampleDTO.asList(YourClassExampleDTO.class);
        int lstSize = lstYourClassExampleDTO.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < lstSize; i++) {
            lstYourClassExampleDTO.get(i);

        }

    }
```